# Why does a new rails app fail to generate due to a gem install error, asking me for a password? What's the solution?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.10

Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2

Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.10

Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2

Ignoring byebug-4.0.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 4.0.3

Ignoring byebug-3.5.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 3.5.1

Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2

Ignoring json-1.8.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.2

Ignoring json-1.8.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.1

Ignoring mysql2-0.3.18 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine mysql2 --version 0.3.18

Ignoring mysql2-0.3.17 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine mysql2 --version 0.3.17

Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2

Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.10

Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.6

Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
You can cancel this installation and run:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
and install the bundled gems to Rubygems using sudo.

Password:

Comment: Bear in mind that we're not standing behind you watching you work, so if you expect help, you're going to have to provide more details. You're using a Mac, yes? What package manager are you using? RVM?

Comment: Sorry, new to this. Yes, Mac 10.13, Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.0. Not using RVM or any package manager, yet.  Hasn't been a need. I've only built a handful of apps and it's been 9 months since I've worked on any projects. Trying to get back into it.  Suddenly, rails new is generating errors. Is it because my gems are out of date? I'm unable to update. I just keep getting a password prompt. Can't seem to get around it.  Will installing a manager allow me to solve this?

Comment: I take that back, I think I'm using rbenv

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the things 
1) remove the gem versions specified by Gemfile 
2) type the command 
sudo bundle install